# Is there a way to format array data directly into a variable to be used in the body of a text e-mail?

Tags: php, arrays, email

I have an array that collects strings of questions passed as such:

```
$myQuestionsPass = array ( " Question 1 passed! " );
if ( $isQ2 == Yes ) {
$myQuestionsPass[] = " Question 2 passed! " ;
}
```

after this array fills with the questions that passed data and filled the array, I then want to dump all the array data of `$myQuestionsPass` directly to the text mail and have it list in a text based email as such:

```
Email output- Congrats
Question 1 passed!
Question 2 passed!
and so on....
```

This is what I have, and it does everything, except it does not seperate each piece of data to the new next line in the text based email body...(`echo` and `print_r` return to the screen of which I don't desire, and `foreach` loops all the way through, that by the time I try to pass the variable to the mail program, it just displays the last question in the array that assigned to `$myQuestionsPass`)

```
$myQuestionsPass = implode( ",",$myQuestionsPass);
```

my mail...

```
$body = "Email output- Congrats
         $myQuestionsPass"
```

results in to a text email that looks like this:

```
Email output- Congrats
Question 1 passed! , Question 2 passed! , Question 3 passed! , Question 4 passed! , and so on....
```

instead of my desired array display of:

```
Email output- Congrats
Question 1 passed!
Question 2 passed!
Question 3 passed!
so on....
```

The newline tag and line break(br) show up as text in the email if I try to use them...

Any help would be appreciated, I have been searching on this for awhile and this was posted out of frustration! Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Have you tried with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073382/newline-not-working-in-php-mail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm understanding fully but you want to output the array in an email?

```
$body="Email output- Congrats\n";
foreach ($myQuestionsPass as $questionPass) {
     $body.=$questionPass."\n";
}
mail("steve@example.com","Results",$body);
```

How does that code not work for you? The `\n` will add newlines and the `.=` will concatenate the question answer to the email body.

Comment: My guess is maybe Steve used single quotes on his newline instead of double quotes. Make sure its `"\n"` not `'\n'` -- its caught me up a few times heh. Otherwise I can't imagine the newlines not working.

Comment: @TheManiac Yeah, I thought that he's probably using single quotes just there, came back to post the comment!

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure what I was doing wrong, but I erased my code and started fresh and the foreach worked. I feel so dumb, but Thank You for helping me get through that! I am all cheers here!