# Can't insert line breaks in email

Tags: php, email

Im using my own `send_mail` function and don't seem to be able to pass new lines to it.

I tried the [double-quote-fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073382/newline-not-working-in-php-mail) but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe those new lines get lost when calling my function?

the function:

```
abstract class util {
    ...
    static function send_email($to,$from,$subject,$message){
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'To: '.$to.'' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: '.$from.'' . "\r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);        
    }
    ...
}
```

the call:

```
    $subject = "Your email activation for ". DOMAIN;
    $message = "Dear ".$this->name.", \r\n Welcome to ********. Click the link below to activate your account and get started. \r\n ".VERIFY_LINK."?code=".$this->code."&id=".$this->id;
    util::send_email($this->email, EMAIL_REGISTER, $subject, $message);
```

yet emails always end up being one-liners

any ideas?

Comment: why not use `HTML` line breaks (`<br>`) ?

Comment: I would highly suggest using someone else's mail-sending library that is used by potentially hundreds of other people, has been extensively debugged and doesn't have security flaws in it.

Comment: </br> <br /> didn't work, maybe because im not sending the html tags. I switched to text/plain, then it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$message = nl2br($message)` function to convert \n to line breaks, since your email is in html. Or you can write your message using `<br />` tags instead of \n for line breaks

Comment: I don't know why I didn't notice the content-type. I switched to text/plain

Answer (score 1):

try using `<br/>` tags instead of /n?

Comment: well, I feeld quite stupid for not noticing. Switched to text/plain, then it worked.

Comment: yup, that'll do.. but if you want to use html, I am sure <br/> tags would do the job.