# How to avoid hardcoded newline from email body?

Tags: php, email, newline

I have an application that sends email with following contents..

```
$message= "Hi, some_content  \n some_content_on_new_line".
```

I want some_content_on_new_line on new line in email, but when the email is sent, "\n" is not interpolated to a newline character. Instead it is displayed as a backslash followed by an 'n'.  How can I prevent this?  This is my email config.

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)
```

Comment: Is the first line you show literally the code you are using?

Comment: Awesome email config I'd say

Comment: Try [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br)

Comment: what's the point here? to have a new line character that works on any OS? you can use the predefined constant PHP_EOL

Comment: possible duplicate of [newline not working in PHP mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073382/newline-not-working-in-php-mail)

Answer (score 1):

If `\n` is showing in the email content then most likely the problem is the use of single quotes to define the string literal.

```
$message= 'Hi, some_content  \n some_content_on_new_line';
// this will show the \n

$message= "Hi, some_content  \n some_content_on_new_line";
// this will interpolate the newline properly
```